# Installation of rcppmlpack2 fails

Tags: r, rcpp

When I try to install `rcppmlpack2` as described in [this blog post](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/using-rcppmlpack2/) I receive the following. I'm installing the package with the following piece of code `remotes::install_github("rcppmlpack/rcppmlpack2")`

```
/usr/local/clang4/bin/clang++ -std=gnu++11 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/clang4/lib -o RcppMLPACK.so LARS.o RcppExports.o coverTreeNeighbor.o init.o kMeans.o linearRegression.o logisticRegression.o naiveBayesClassifier.o -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib/ -lm -l/usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.dylib -l/usr/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib -l/usr/local/lib/libboost_unit_test_framework-mt.dylib -l/usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization-mt.dylib -lmlpack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin16/6.3.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: library not found for -l/usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.dylib
clang-4.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RcppMLPACK.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppMLPACK’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/RcppMLPACK’
Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘/var/folders/tc/4ygpk4nd6tqctkm5gdnw85340000gn/T//RtmpQjVuQL/remotesa73514ed0ed5/rcppmlpack-rcppmlpack2-377b445’ had non-zero exit status
```

My session info

```
R Under development (unstable) (2018-01-26 r74169)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] drat_0.1.4     compiler_3.5.0 tools_3.5.0    yaml_2.1.16    remotes_1.1.1
```

Can someone point me in the right direction of why I cannot install the package. The file `libarmadillo.dylib` exists according to R.

```
> file.exists("/usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.dylib")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: How did you build and install MLPACK ?

Comment: I've followed the instructions in the [readme](https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack) file. So I first created a folder named build, ran `cmake ../`. I then ran `make`, and afterwards `make install`

Comment: Oh, I overlooked something: `ld: library not found for -l/usr/local/lib/libarmadillo.dylib`  You may also need to install Armadillo as MLPACK links to it.

Comment: It's a mac. This is broken unless compiled against the `clang4` binary.

Comment: I've already installed Armadillo? It may be a stupid question @coatless, but  does that mean it is not possible to install rcppmlpack2 on a Mac?

Comment: Not quite. Just the current setup requires a lot of additional work to get it active on a mac. (c.f. compiling armadillo + mlpack using `clang4` and the xcode cli system library)